# What is the difference between incognito and cacheEnabled props in React Native WebView?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, caching, webview, react-native-webview

First of all, I have a basic level of English so I hope that you understand.

What is the difference between incognito and cacheEnabled props in React Native WebView? react-native-webview doc don't have a detailed explanation.

**incognito**
*Does not store any data within the lifetime of the WebView.*

**cacheEnabled**
*Sets whether WebView should use browser caching.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the source code, the functionality is different between iOS and Android:

**iOS**:

Uses `WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent`, which does not store anything to the disk.

**Android**:

1. Removes all cookies from `CookieManager`.
2. Clears all caches, forms, password etc. and disables caching
3. Sets cache mode to `LOAD_NO_CACHE` (always from network)

All other than the first step also apply to `cacheEnabled=false`. I'm not sure how caching works in `WKWebView`. It may not cache anything by default, which would mean the incognito functionality is inline with Android. `cacheEnabled=true/false` does nothing in iOS.